# angular app separated http loaders

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-ui

I have a small angular 1.x application. At this moment I'm using angular-http-loader as a full screen loader.

The problem is that when I am using ui-bootstrap Typeahead, I don't want to show this big loader but to use some other spinners that are not showing for the whole page.

Is there any libraries can provide loaders that I can turn off for specific request like search query in input? Or any tips how to implement this.